# Injecting a slf4j Logger: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, logging, dependency-injection, slf4j

I want to inject a Logger into a bean in my maven dynamic web project running on WildFly 10.

**I added the dependency in my POM. The scope is provided in WildFly:**

```
    <!-- Logger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**I created a Producer:**

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Singleton
public class LoggerProducer {

    @Produces
    Logger createLogger(final InjectionPoint ip) {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
    }
}
```

**And then I tried to inject a Logger:**

```
@Inject
private Logger log;
```

At this point I am already getting a Warning:

**No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-346 §5.2.2]**

And when I try to use it, I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private init.StartupBean.log
  at init.StartupBean.log(StartupBean.java:0)
```

What am I missing ? Did I forget something ?

Comment: I have no experience with injection so no answer from me, just a question: How would the DI-Mechanism know it has to use your LoggerProducer for a Logger? Logger itself is not unique a classname.

Comment: I get no such exceptions on glassfish, but glassfish 4.1.1 have its own set of problems.

Comment: I had the same problem. Then recognized that I used different Logger Classes. We have to be sure to import the right Logger Class at injecten and producer point.

Answer (score 0):

Even years later I had the same issue when performing tests with Arquillian. In Arquillian you include (in general) only the classes needed for the test. The CDI resource producers are in my case kept in a single class called Resources. I discovered that all classes that are referred by the Resources.class must be included as well. Otherwise you get the error message of this question. Probably obvious once you know.

Main issue: There must be a root cause (ClassNotFound or whatever) that is most unfortunately not propagated to the console, leaving us in the dark.